# Simulate actual button press on mobile-safari on iPod Touch / iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I am building a web-based tool for internal purposes for my company that runs on an ipod touch. It's working fine, but there are a few quirks such as not being able to auto-focus on a text field when a page loads without the user actually tapping the screen (I can "focus" the field, but the keyboard is not active). Additionally, I cannot programmatically trigger sounds to play (I am using the jPlayer library). What it seems to come down to is this:

Is there some way I can trick the browser on an ipod touch 4 to thinking the user has actually tapped a specific div on the screen? If I can do that, I can solve every other issue. Since this is for internal purposes, I am free to make any modifications needed. However, I need to able to do keep the "app" code in HTML5 and JavaScript for a myriad of reasons. Perhaps an app with a modification to safari to allow this, then I can run my site in that app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Perhaps an app with a modification to safari to allow this, then I can run my site in that app?

Yes, you could write a really simple app with just a `UIWebView` in which you display your HTML5 based app. If you need extra things such as back button etc. you would have to implement that (it's also not very difficult). The `UIWebView` should behave mostly exactly like Safari, so it should be a *de facto* "app with a modification to safari".

You could then give the right element focus and call

```
[webView becomeFirstResponder];
```

The sounds could also be played programmatically by simply requesting the appropriate URL.

I think with this setup the additional effort in terms of coding beyond your existing web based tool is minimal. However, this assumes you have Xcode, know some basic Objective-C and are familiar with the procedures of ad hoc or company distribution of "real" apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a timed event

Comment: As in setTimeout(function() { doStuff(); }); ?